# create a table and insert values into table

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7

I have created a table using the following code, and it works

```
def createSQLCreateTableCommand(tableName, columns, foreignKeys):
    columns = ["%s"%(c) for c in columns]
    foreignKeys = ["FOREIGN KEY (%s) REFERENCES %s(%s)"%(fk[0],fk[1],fk[2]) for fk in foreignKeys]
    cmd = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (%s)"""%(tableName,','.join(columns+foreignKeys))
    return cmd


sqlEx = createSQLCreateTableCommand("class",[
            "name text", 
            "role text"],
            [])
conn = sqlite.connect(":memory:")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(sqlEx)

cursor.execute("""SELECT tbl_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'""")
print cursor.fetchall()
```

Then, I would like to insert some values into the table ,and I write the following function, but it gives error message "table class has no column named 'name', 'role'". I was confused because I just created a table in previous function and it worked.

```
def createSQLInsertCommand(tableName,columns):
    columns = ["%s"%(c) for c in columns]
    cmd = """INSERT INTO %s (%s) Values (?)""" %(tableName,columns)
    return cmd

sqlValidate = createSQLInsertCommand("class",["name","role"])

cursor.executemany(sqlValidate,[("Brian","Instructor"),("Steven","TA"),("Bob","TA"),("Jody","Student")])
cursor.execute("""SELECT * from class""")
print cursor.fetchall()
```

Anyone can help me fix my second function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your function is doing wrong and how you can fix it

```
>>> columns = ["name","role"]
>>> tableName = 'class'
>>> """INSERT INTO %s (%s) Values (?)""" %(tableName,columns)
"INSERT INTO class (['name', 'role']) Values (?)"
>>> """INSERT INTO %s (%s) Values (?)""" %(tableName,','.join(columns))
'INSERT INTO class (name,role) Values (?)'
```

Also, if you are inserting 2 columns you must have 2 `?` placeholders which should be generated based on the columns eg.

```
>>> """INSERT INTO %s (%s) Values (%s)""" %(tableName,','.join(columns), ','.join(['?' for c in columns]))
'INSERT INTO class (name,role) Values (?,?)'
```